# Error Migrating DialogFlow ES agent to CX

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I am trying to migrate an agent from ES to CX using these instructions. https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/how/migrate

But after doing everything, I am getting the error:

```
Entity Type: Traptype
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x38 pc=0xa8efaa]
goroutine 1 [running]:
main.migrateEntities({0xdb3ae0, 0x14465a0})
        C:/Users/...../Chatbot Code/migrate/main.go:359 +0x68a
main.main()
        C:/Users/..../Chatbot Code/migrate/main.go:486 +0xa5
exit status 2
```

Traptype is an entity I created in the ES chatbot. Do you have any suggestions on what to do next?